# Turn off all menus for a screenshot

Tags: interface

I need to take screenshots from my working area often and don't know how to get rid of all these menus and buttons. I don't want to render, because then I'll need to set up the camera and so on, and also I don't need a quality pic for my purposes.

Is there a way?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are different ways to accomplish your goal, depending on your specific needs.

**Viewport Render**

The viewport can be rendered through *View > Viewport Render Image*.

[image: Viewport Render Image]

**Screenshot of the active area**

A screenshot of the active area can be created using the following steps:

1. Hide the gizmos
   [image]
2. Open the operator search <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for *Save Screenshot*.
3. Run the *Save Screenshot* operator (`bpy.ops.screen.screenshot()`).
4. Uncheck the *Full Screen* property (this will only include the active area) and save the image.
   [image: File browser]

**Fullscreen mode & third-party software**

The following steps enabled the fullscreen mode and allow you to take a screenshot with a third-party tool:

1. Hide the gizmos
   [image: Hide Gizmos]
2. Switch to fullscreen mode through *View > Area > Toggles Fullscreen Area* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>).
3. Use a third-party tool to create the screenshot
4. In order to leave the fullscreen mode move the mouse cursor to the upper right corner and click on the icon [image: Leave fullscreen icon]. Alternatively you can also press the shortcut again <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for all the variants! As you could see, I already use third-party tool to create the screenshot (as I attached one). I hoped there is a way to quickly see a viewport without all the menus though, but if there's no such way, it's okay. It seems Viewport render can help.

Comment: The second option does hide the menus. Or do you not consider clicking a couple buttons and hitting a hotkey quick? ;)  (In addition to the button with the red square around it I'd also click the button to the right of it to hide a few extras.)

Answer (score 8):

You can click view>viewport image to take a render screenshot of what is on the screen.

[image]

Blender will automatically create a snapshot of exactly what is in the viewport.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 2.7x, you can follow these steps:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> = for toggle fullscreen area.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> = for toggle window fullscreen.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> = it will open the "Save Screenshot" window.
- Set a name and location to the screenshot to be taken.
- Press *Save Screenshot* button.

To show the menus and the screen again as it was before, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> respectively.